# Confused about the linearity of Frechet derivative?

Tags: functional-analysis

Frechet derivative is a linear operator. But directional derivative may be not.
So this means if a function has directional derivative, it is not sure it has Frechet derivative. 
Take a simple example $\frac{1}{2}(ax-b)^2, x\in R^1,a,b\neq0$, the directional derivative is $av(ax-b),v \in R^1$. Thanks to @user74674 , $2av(ax-b)$ is linear operator w.r.t $v$.

$lim_{v\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left\|a^2xv+\frac{1}{2}a^2v^2-avb-A_x(v)\right\|_p}{\left\|v\right\|_q}$=$lim_{v\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left\|a^2xv+\frac{1}{2}a^2v^2-avb-a^2vx+avb\right\|_p}{\left\|v\right\|_q}$=$lim_{v\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left\|\frac{1}{2}a^2v^2\right\|_p}{\left\|v\right\|_q}$=0.

So in this simple example, Frechet derivative and the directional derivative is the same.

Could you tell me is there any condition can tell when they are same?

And http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrechetDerivative.html, this definition is wrong? Right?

Answer (score 2):

Directional derivative has two arguments: base point $x$ and direction vector $v$. Linearity refers to linearity with respect to $v$, not $x$. (This becomes more clear when you move to functions on manifolds, where the underlying space of points has no linear structure at all.)

In your example, the directional derivative at point $x$ in direction $v$ is 
$$\begin{split}\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+hv)-f(x)}{h} &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac12 \frac{ (ax+ahv-b)^2-(ax-b)^2}{h} \\ &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac12 \frac{ 2ahv(ax-b) +a^2h^2v^2 }{h} \\&=  av(ax-b) \end{split}$$ 
which is a *linear* function of $v$. In general, the directional derivative of a differentiable function on $\mathbb R$ at a point $x$ is the *linear* operator $v\mapsto f'(x)v$. Just think of $x$ as fixed and $v$ as a variable: this is the sort of linearity we are talking about.

Comment: ,Thank you. So the directional derivative is the gradient times the direction. But for linearity,  for Frechet derivative is linear operator w.r.t the 'x' argument. The Frechet does not have directional vector.

Comment: @Vivian Yes, when the function is differentiable.

Comment: ,But for linearity, for Frechet derivative is linear operator w.r.t the 'x' argument. The Frechet does not have directional vector.

Comment: @Vivian That is wrong on both counts. The dependency on $x$ is not considered at all. The linearity is with respect to direction vector; on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) it is denoted by $h$.

Comment: ,Thank you for remind. It seems that my script is wrong :（。  In this way, $lim_{v\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left\|2a^2xv+a^2v^2-2avb-A_x(v)\right\|_p}{\left\|v\right\|_q}$

Answer (score 2):

A small remark. If a mapping is Frechet differentiable at a point, then it has directional derivatives at that point in all directions. However, the existence of directional derivatives in all directions at a point does not imply that the mapping is Frechet differentiable at the given point.